# Update automaticly when there is a change

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

**I'm just beginning with programming**

*Index.php*

```
    <?
    include_once('UserStatus.php');
    $online = new UserStatus();
    $online->Online();
    ?>
```

*UserStatus.php*

```
<?php

include_once('connect.php');

class UserStatus {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connect();
        $this->db = $this->db->DbConnect();
    }
    public function Online(){

        $check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='online'");

        if($check->rowCount() == 1) {
            foreach($check as $online){
            echo $online['name'].'<br>';
            }
        } 
    }

}



?>
```

Now i'm getting the list `where status='online'` i want to know how to update this list without reloading the page.

Example User1 allready logged in so User1 sees Online users: User1.
Whenever User2 is logging in i want to update it to the screen of User1 without reloading this page.

I want to use same method with a message board.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a hint, this question is very vague as a complete answer would be very extensive on this matter.

Comment: You'd need to incorporate a couple more technologies to actually get this to update on any users screen in real-time. A client that runs in the users browser (presumably in JavaScript) that will update their view without getting a new page, and a server to notify all clients of changes.

Comment: @NebezBriefkani, there's also the fact that PHP is a stateless language and cannot garantee that a user is *really* there at any given time... without at least using WebSockets or some kind of heartbeat/ping requests.

Comment: To reload without refreshing, use Ajax.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a "active session" table were you record the time stamp for each user as a unique row that they were last active, and delete the rows once the timestamp is older than a certain duration (Eg 15 minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to intermittently query the DB to check for active users. Maybe use a JavaScript `setInterval()` to run a function every so often. Then in that function use a jQuery ajax `$.get` request to get the list of active users, then update the content on the screen in the response function.